# How to download all personal GEE scripts?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been working on a few projects in GEE for the past year. Access to GEE code editor has now been revoked (I've been told that Google wants the US Fish and Wildlife Service to pay to use GEE now). I would like to at least retain the scripts that I've written. In the developers guide it states that "The Scripts manager stores private, shared and example scripts in Git repositories hosted by Google." Is there a way to access personal scripts in the git repository without having to sign into the code editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The script repositories that you access from the Earth Engine Code Editor are stored in [Google Cloud Source](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/). The can be accessed via a web browser using the following URL pattern:

https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/USERNAME

Script repositories can be cloned locally with Git. For example, to clone your default repository:

```
git clone https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/USERNAME/default
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but I'm getting the same message I get when trying to access the code editor "You don't have access to this service. To request access, contact the administrator for your organization’s Google services." My colleague has already spoken to IT and they said google now wants $ for government use of GEE. I see you work for GEE, do you know if there is truth to that?

Comment: The error message indicates that an administrator within your organization has disabled access to Earth Engine. The Earth Engine Terms of Service (https://earthengine.google.com/terms/) allow for "development, research, or educational purposes" and "evaluation in a production environment", but do not allow for "sustained commercial purposes". The terms have not changed since 2015, so I don't know why Earth Engine has been disabled for your organization at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think they know either. I've been in touch with IT today. They are trying to figure out what is going on, but said I shouldn't have ever been able to sign in with a fws.gov email address because google cloud source isn't approved for government use, or something like that...but I was granted access back in Dec 2016 and have been using it for two years with a government email address. I guess they just changed something this Monday and now I can't get in. It's my worst nightmare.

Comment: Tyler, is it not working anymore? I'm trying to run git clone without success...

Answer (score 2):

To complete Tyler's answer, you might need to have a password and log-in first. If after doing:

```
git clone https://earthengine.googlesource.com/users/USERNAME/default
```

You get a message like:

> Invalid authentication credentials. Please generate a new identifier:
> https://earthengine.googlesource.com/new-password

You will indeed have to go to https://earthengine.googlesource.com/new-password, log-in etc, which will give you instructions on how to configure and add your password. Then you can run the `git clone` line.

See the instructions from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/playground):

> Click on the settings icon next to the repository name for instructions on
> cloning the repository. Note that you can browse the repositories to
> which you have access by going to earthengine.googlesource.com. For
> some Git operations, you may need to create authentication credentials
> by going to the Generate Password link at the top of the
> earthengine.googlesource.com page.

Comment: I think this is the most complete answer.